# Regex to check for any number of 4 or more digits EXCEPT specific numbes

Tags: regex, numbers

a client is asking for a regex to check for any number higher than 999 to remind to add a thousand separator e.g. 1,000, however they don't want to get false positives for commonly mentioned years (2019, 2020, 2021) etc. Is there any way to achieve this, i.e. "any number of 4 or more digits EXCEPT these specific numbers"?

I've considered the below, but this will ignore any number where the first digit is 2, so will miss out anything between 2000-2999 as well as 20,000, 2,000,000 etc., which definitely need to have thousand separators added.

```
[1|3-9]\d{3,}
```

Is this something that can actually be done with a regex? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like this? `\b(?!20(?:2[01]|19))\d{4,}` https://regex101.com/r/w6JkRE/1

Comment: How would you determine if a number is a year? Every number between 1 and (at least) 2020 can be interpreted as year...

Comment: @ChristianBaumann of course, that's why I specified "commonly mentioned years" - this client is only really worried about false positives for years in the near past/future, as those are likely to come up a lot more frequently than others

Comment: "Commonly" and "past/near future" is pretty unspecific...

Comment: @ChristianBaumann again, that's why I specified the examples of 2019, 2020 and 2021 for this client's case, and that's what thefourthbird's answer has allowed me to do, so the problem is solved

Comment: You said `(2019, 2020, 2021) etc` ...

Comment: @ChristianBaumann my intention with "etc" was more that, if required, further specific numbers to exclude could be added to the set, not that I was expecting there to be some magical way of determining if a number is a year, but I understand the confusion

Answer (score 1):

Using `[1|3-9]\d{3,}` will not match 2, but will also give you a partial match in `21234`

Note that you can omit the `|` as it would match it literally in the character class.

---

Before matching 4 or more digits, if supported, you can assert using a negative lookahead that what is directly to the right is not 2019, 2020 or 2021

At the beginning you can add a word boundary or for example an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string.

```
\b(?!20(?:2[01]|19)\b)\d{4,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1SJqQf/1)

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly for what I'm looking for! I don't know why I didn't think of using lookaheads in that way.

Comment: It should be `\b(?!20(?:2[01]|19)\b)\d{4,}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sharp! Updated, now the pattern can match 20211 indeed